# Android Gradle How to build for Android Google APIs 4.2.2 not for Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, build, gradle, google-maps-android-api-2

Is it possible to build for Android Google APIs SDK instead of the general Android SDK with gradle?

I need the Google Maps APIs in my project therefore I need to change the build target
I can find only samples with the build version "17"
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion '17.0.0'

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Do you want to use deprecated API v1 or new API v2?

Comment: I use that one
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapActivity

so basically v1

Comment: Have you just started your project? In that case you will not make v1 to work.

Comment: No it's a old project. I have api keys

Comment: Try this, maybe help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35450417/errorcause-failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-google-inc-google-apis23/36776374#36776374

Answer (score 90):

i figured it out:

1) use the Android SDK Manager and get the Google APIs for the android versions you want (start it from Android Studio, it's seperate from your old sdk manager if you used eclipse before)

2)

- Go to "File > Project Structure > SDKs"
- click the plus sign and select "Android SDK"
- a popup will appear, navigate to your Android Studio installation folder and select the "sdk" subfolder
- another popup will appear: select "Google APIs (#.#.#)"

3) In the same Project Structure window: select "Android #.#.# Google APIs"the Project SDK click Apply/OK

4) Now in your build.gradle files replace

```
android {
    ...
    compileSdkVersion 17
    ...
}
```

with

```
android {
    ...
    compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:17"
    ...
}
```

6) restart Android Studio

this did it for me for google apis 16.
If you're still having troubles:

- Go to "File > Project Structure > SDKs"
- Select your Google API > classpath
- Make sure the Google APIs jar files are in there
  (e.g. Android Studio/sdk/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-16/libs/maps.jar)
- if not add them manually (had to do this for apis 17)
- restart Android Studio

Comment: This worked for me, when I was porting earlier eclipse android-library projects. All i had to do was to copy the property string 'target' from the eclipse project file 'project.properties' so it matches the sdk with Google APIs 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:15' that i was using

Comment: I`m working with an old legacy project that uses Google Maps api v1, and this was the only solution across the internet that worked for me (using Android Studio 0.5.4).

Comment: I had to use some other SDK version not provided by google, thanks to you I figured out `compileSdkVersion` should be equal to `Vendor:Target Name:API Level`