# package com.google.android.maps does not exist Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps

I've been working on a project which includes maps, however I made an error and I have had to create a new project.  I have copied across all my classes, res folders, libraries etc.  However now I am getting 101 ERRORS!!

There are all a knock on of this:

package com.google.maps does not exist.

I have selected a target google api:

[image: Target SDK]

I've included the jar files as dependencies as follows:

[image: dependencies]

It was working fine in my previous project but now that I have had to create a new project it doesn't work.  I'm obviously omitting something but I can't think of what.  I am using Android Studio and it is a gradle build

If someone could help me I would really appreciate it because it is extremely frustrating...

Oh and I have it declared in my manifest

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

so please, if anyone has come across this before I'd appreciate it.  I've already searched online and checked out this:

http://code.davidjanes.com/blog/2009/11/13/18-hours-of-jar-hell-with-android-google-maps/

although helpful it told me what I already knew...so please please help!!

***EDIT***

Ok, I know what the problem is, I just don't know how to fix it.  I am referencing maps.jar, however, in this project there is no maps.jar, in my previous project there was in the external library.  The external library had Android 4.1.2 Google APIs and included there was maps.jar, however, I can't seem to create a project with the external library containing that, I don't know why.  I have tried to change the build target by going file -> other setting -> default project structure and changing it there but it doesn't work...can anyone suggest what I might need to do to ensure if I create a project to have the Google APIs included in the external library?  Or what changes I need to make to my current project

Comment: What version of Android Studio?

Comment: @ScottBarta 0.4.3   Any ideas?

Comment: Some bugs of this nature were fixed in 0.4.3; you could try 0.4.5, where more of those bugs were fixed. Or try the workaround of closing your proiject, deleting the .idea folder, and re-importing it.

Comment: @ScottBarta  so close the project, delete the idea folder in my finder then reopen my project, and copy the folder in again?

Comment: Don't copy it in -- re-import (not re-open) your project and let it recreate the contents of the folder.

Comment: thanks for that tip but unfortunately didn't work...it's so frustrating..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47902/discussion-between-scott-barta-and-dj-doo)

Comment: that google maps is deprecated and no longer works, you need to use google maps v2 which is in google play services

Comment: @tyczj thanks for your comment but I'm not using the actual maps just map activity etc...plus it was working in the previous project that I was working on only two days ago before I made the error

Comment: Does not matter what you are doing, you cannot get a map key anymore for google maps v1

Comment: I don't need a map key...I need to change the build target to google api

Comment: would be nice if the parent tags of `uses-library` where added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this link, it showed me how to change the external library and now it works...thanks to those who helped

[Android Gradle How to build for Android Google APIs 4.2.2 not for Android 4.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748273/android-gradle-how-to-build-for-android-google-apis-4-2-2-not-for-android-4-2-2)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to **build.gradle** file

```
dependencies {
...
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.3.0'
...
}
```

Comment: Done that. Didn't help. Of course, now is `implementation´ and the version newer as well.