# Including Google API (maps) in non Gradle Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps

I have a legacy Android project (for Android API version 8 to 17) and I am struggling to get it to build correctly. It is a non-gradle project, and I can not convert it to gradle just yet (there is a build server that will fail then). It has already been edited in Android Studio before me by a person no longer here, and it landed on my desk. I have it all building now, but one problem remains. The project has a activity that extends "com.google.android.maps.MapActivity", but I could not get the project in Android Studio to be able to see that class, I could not find a way to make it depend on Google API's, so I ended up making the project depend on the maps.jar file from the Google API's version 17. Now the project compiles, but at runtime I get this error:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: dk.some.domain.ui.branchinfo.BranchViewController
```

My guess is that it is compiled with one version of the Google API's (maps) version, but the phone has a different version or something. How do I fix this problem?

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer in this post:

[Android Gradle How to build for Android Google APIs 4.2.2 not for Android 4.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748273/android-gradle-how-to-build-for-android-google-apis-4-2-2-not-for-android-4-2-2)

The funny thing was that I also had to set my module SDK to be the Google API and not the Android SDK, but it works.