# how to use multiple add-ons in android studio

Tags: android-studio, add-on

I can use compileSdkVersion like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748273/android-gradle-how-to-build-for-android-google-apis-4-2-2-not-for-android-4-2-2). But what about multiple add-ons?

Comment: I make a mistake.. While it is a add-on, it is a android target itself.