# package com.google.android.maps does not exist?

Tags: android

I am new to android studio and was importing one of my project everything is working except it cannot include google maps library and is giving following errors:

```
error:package com.google.android.maps does not exist 
error:package com.google.android.maps does not exist
```

I have seen different links of the same type of question but they are not working.
Below are some dependencies details:

> Project Structure:

[image]

> build.graddle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "redixbit.restaurant"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile files('libs/easyandroidanimationslibrary-v0.5.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'

}
```

Importing Google maps library in code:

[image]

Please help to sort out my issue.

Comment: Try following the steps here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748273/android-gradle-how-to-build-for-android-google-apis-4-2-2-not-for-android-4-2-2

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this same issue and I needed to include the awareness service:

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-awareness:16.0.0'`

Comment: This is the right answer b.c all other services of a map is included within awareness subtitle according to latest google developer's api setup site https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 0):

Add into dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
```

Comment: This is what i'm getting on adding the above dependencies: Gradle sync failed: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
   Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Answer (score 0):

add this gradle in your dependence

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1
```

Comment: The following error is there when added above code to dependency : Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Use this:-

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
```

Comment: i am getting error message Failed to resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services....

Comment: Delete that dependency.

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0' delete this and add the above mentioned dependencies.

Comment: These are new dependencies :compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile files('libs/easyandroidanimationslibrary-v0.5.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1' but error is still same Failed to resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location...

Answer (score 0):

According to updates **google play services** libraries faced some changes in updates

Just add :

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:X..Y.Z"
```

It works pretty well